How detectable would Earth life or technology be with current methods, depending on cosmic distance?
For the sake of this question, let's assume intelligent life exists elsewhere in the Universe, and let's also assume it has a similar level of science and technology to humanity at present. How far would that alien world have to be from Earth in order to detect anything about life or technology on our planet?
Furthermore, how does the answer change as we vary the distance? E.g. with current methods, how much about Earth would be detectable from 10ly vs 100ly, 1000ly etc?
EDIT: I realize similar questions have been asked before, but they are close to a decade old, and the answers point to research on detection capabilities that's sometimes even older. In the past few years, I've come across several news articles discussing research on bio- and technosignatures, so I was wondering if the answer to my question has now changed.

Does this answer your question? https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8146/how-far-away-could-we-detect-that-earth-has-life

@Allure somewhat - the question is mostly about detecting life, although the answers do go a bit into one possible technosignature - radio emissions. I wonder if in the 9 years since the question was asked we've gotten further ahead in what we could detect, and at what distances.

See also https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8605/if-alpha-centauri-as-solar-system-exactly-mirrored-our-own-what-would-we-be-ab and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/18059/can-seti-certify-whether-or-not-proxima-b-is-inhabited-by-beings-using-electroma

and https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/how-would-we-detect-an-earth-doppelganger-planet

@ProfRob thanks - I did go over some of the linked questions and saw your answers there. Has anything changed about our detection capabilities since them? Some of the literature you've cited - e.g. Cullers and Tarter - is from 20+ years ago, and I'm aware more research has been done recently on techno- and biosignatures.

Maybe you could modify your question to say/ask precisely that, so that it is not closed as a duplicate.

The distance to reliably detect life-bearing planets is much less than the distance to fortuitously detect such planets.  The closest Sun-like stars, such as Alpha Centauri, could host Earth-like planets teeming with life and with an oxygen-rich atmosphere, and we would have no clue.  The Fermi paradox is a paradox not because technological civilizations are (easily) detectable at a distance, but that they should already be right here in this solar system: the rate of civilizational expansion-- even without magic FTL-- should be so large compared to the time available.

Does this answer your question? How far away could we detect that Earth has life?

@ProfRob I've updated the question as you suggested, to reflect that I'm interested in the current state of the art. Thanks!

@antlersoft thanks for that perspective. There are still a lot of assumption in there - that civilizational expansion is desirable/sought, that it's able or intended to cover the entire galaxy, etc. etc. In many ways, the Fermi paradox strikes me as asking: "if they were like us in essential respects, then where are they?" Of course, the if-part of this question is highly conjectural.
